# In Excel, how do I write a formula so that Cell (B18) will display a specified value, based on variable responses in (B19-B21)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have 5 possible values (chosen from a dropdown) that can be entered in cells B19-B21:

> N/A, NOT STARTED, IN PROCESS, OVERDUE, COMPLETE

The condition I want to write for the header row B18 would say in plain English:

If B19-B21 all = some combination of "COMPLETE" or "N/A" then B18= "COMPLETE"; Else = "INCOMPLETE"

I have read several similar discussions on conditional formatting but am having trouble finding where to start with the above scenario.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(B19:B21,{"COMPLETE","N/A"}))=3,"COMPLETE","INCOMPLETE")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about counting all the COMPLETE and N/A up to the total count, like:

> =IF(COUNTIF(B19:B21, "N/A") + COUNTIF(B19:B21, "COMPLETE") = 3, "COMPLETE", "INCOMPLETE")

Then when you have all of the cell either COMPLETE or N/A, the counter is 3 and you have it COMPLETE, otherwise it will be INCOMPLETE.

**Edit:**

If you want to take it a step further and count when all of them are N/A, you can do it with another IF like:

> =IF(COUNTIF(B19:B21, "N/A") = 3, "N/A", IF(COUNTIF(B19:B21, "N/A") + COUNTIF(B19:B21, "COMPLETE") = 3, "COMPLETE", "INCOMPLETE"))

And there you have it, when all of them are N/A, then you have N/A. 
When they are a mix of N/A and COMPLETE, then it's COMPLETE, otherwise, it is INCOMPLETE.

Comment: Thank you this worked well.  Do you know if it's possible to take it a step further; the above should remain true, but - if ALL answers B19:B21 = "N/A" then the B18 should display N/A?   So now B18 can display 3 possible values N/A, INCOMPLETE, COMPLETE

Comment: @christinabean There you have it edited to account when all of them are N/A

Comment: thank you, I understand how this works now and your example worked like a charm.